# How often do you write a new SQL queries or do you try to use existing ones?

Tags: java, c#, sql, database, oracle

I haven't found a similar question. I'd love to hear suggestions and opinions.

It's clear that it's better to have a query that returns only the information you need.
If we work with a larger database, we usually already have a lot of queries for each table with different criteria, simple or complex or dynamic.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction tr WHERE tr.progress_date = '?'; -- about 20 rows
```

But, when at some point we need specific information from a database. 
Do you always write a new query for that case?
For example:

```
SELECT SUM(tr.amount) FROM transaction tr WHERE tr.progress_date = ? AND tr.sender = ?;
```

Or use some existing if similar and don' return much more data, plus do additional simple filtering or search on the back-end side? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction tr WHERE tr.progress_date = '?'; -- about 20 rows

|
V

double sum = transactions.stream().mapToDouble(t -> t.getAmount()).sum();
```

***Note that it's not a small software and often a new situation arises where some information is needed only for one particular case.***

Assume that the data is not cached and that it is Oracle, Postgres or MySql database

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like Hibernate?

Comment: If you're going to use a query over and over again but the parameters are different, I would use a stored procedure.

Comment: @azurefrog The current project doesn't use Hibernate. But if I use Hibernate, the question would be the same.

Comment: @ Alex  We also use procedures. Just thinking, often changing and adding parameters for special cases can turn into hard-to-maintain code and unclear?
The same issue would be that these queries are procedures. Modifying an existing one, adding a new one, or using an existing one with backend processing?

Comment: I was writing an answer suggesting database views together with possibly JPA entities + QueryDSL (or a set of plain JDBC queries) but the over-zealous regulars closed the question before I managed to submit the answer. In short, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

you want the RDBMS to do the heavy lifting when querying large tables. Obviously always use PreparedStatement with parameters and, when needed, indexes or performing joins.

In case of small dataset (ie your 20 rows example) it is acceptable to perform filtering/processing in your Java code, sometimes can be an advantage as you can have one query used by different Java methods.

I would (and I have) adopt a mix approach, with the option to later on refactor the in-memory Java filtering with a dedicated SQL query when the performance difference is noticeable.